# Faces disappearing after import to Unity

Tags: unity

I have a model, and after importing it to Unity some faces are missing. It's not about normals, because in blender I activated backface culling and it is still visible. Here are some images :

[image: mesh in blender]

As you can see, the current face in red outline is clearly visible, also I have backface culling active, believe me.

[image: missing faces in unity]

And here, in the red outline the same place - the face is not visible. Also, this happened not just here, it is also in random places all over the mesh. Additionally, as you can see in the blue outline, the preview has no holes (it is a bit small so I don't know if you can see it).

Also I uploaded [the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8323BCjcu4zR2hyd0lwRUt3ejg/view?usp=sharing). I couldn't upload it anywhere else because of it's size. As for the unity file, well just import the model into unity, and you will see. Please help, thanks!

Comment: You have massive n-gons making up your terrain, which makes for really bad topology. Regardless of whether this is what's causing the problem in Unity, you should really consider changing your modeling approach. That's about all I can tell you. :-/

Comment: If I were you, I would use the Shrinkwrap Modifier to retopo your terrain to something more low-poly, and then scale the whole thing down to a more reasonable size as well. [Here is an example of the kind of result you could get from doing retopo.](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3924/) (I had to delete your original mesh data because it was too large.)